# how to use common inputs for two forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, servlets

i want to create landing page which has two form one for login and another foe register.
but my design is like as following fig.(i try to explain in this fig.) and i want use nested form.
login form  is inside registration form.

when user click on login submit data to login.jsp and for register button submit to register.jsp

i know nested form is not possible in html but any other method available in JavaScript or jsp so i can implement this functionality.

so i want to use these email and password inputs for login form and also for registration form also.

```
 __________________________________________
|                                          |
|  ___________________________             |
| |                           |            |
| |                           |            |
| |  email                    |            |
| |                           |            |
| |                           |            |
| |                           |  Login     |
| |                           |            |
| |  password                 |            |
| |                           |            |
| |                           |            |
| |___________________________|            |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|  First Name                              |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|  Last Name                               |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|  Birth Day                               |
|                                          |
|                 Register                 |
|__________________________________________|
```

Thank You.

Comment: Do you need to have two forms?  When you add the extra registration inputs, could you just change the form action?

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single form which submits to `user.jsp` and branch based on which submit button (`<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">`  or `<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">`) appears in the submitted data.

Ignore all the fields you don't care about if the Login branch is followed.

Answer (score 1):

Forms should not be nested. It goes against the [html5 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element).

> **4.10.3 The `form` element**
>
> **Content model:**
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

You could create two separate forms, with hidden email & password fields in the latter one. Then attach a function that copies those fields from one form to the other when user clicks `register`-button.

Comment: That adds an unnecessary dependancy on JavaScript, and is rather more complicated then just ignoring the unwanted fields.

Comment: Quentin, your answer works only if both forms have the same `action` parameter. That is not always the case.

Comment: My answer states that they should be changed to have the same action attribute. This isn't a situation (such as wanting to send the data to a third party with one of the buttons) where that is hard to achieve.